# Spring Boot Scheduling Booking Window for Movie Ticketing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I'm  working on a movie ticketing system - Spring Boot Microservices. The requirement is Theatre owners provides input on movie that includes booking start/end date and time.

Assuming I have a scheduler microservices, what is the best approach to trigger jobs for allowing/closing booking for a theater. I know `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled`, but need expert opinion if that suffice for this use case for large scale system?

Also any input on efficient Cron expression to use will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Spring Boot is designed for large scale production-ready features.  Spring's scheduling module is quite robust.  Your Cron expression question is really broad and unclear, you may want to consider rewording.  There are tons of articles/tutorials online that explain Cron expressions, maybe some googleing will get you the guidance you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate spring boot with [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)  for large scale system. Quartz will be run a service separate with your system